# How to execute a scenario from another scenario?

Tags: python-behave

Below is the example where I want to execute a scenario in another scenario. Is there any way to do this?

```
Scenario: scenario-A
   Create an object obj-A
   Read  'key1' from the object obj-A

Scenario: scenario-B
   Step1: Create an object obj-B
   Step2: Read 'key2' from obj-B
   Step3: # I want to execute scenario-A here. This gives me value of 'key-1'
   Step4: Perform an operation using 'key1' and 'key2'
```

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make much sense from perspective of BDD, so why would you need that? Can you update the post with  actual example, rather than generic scenarios? Because when answer is to do that, generally you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Hello Tymoteusz,  I have updated the description. Can you please take a look and advice if it is a right approach.? I am trying to reuse the scenario-A here so that I do not have to write steps from scenario-A in scenario-B. Instead if I could just tell behave to run scenario-A from scenario-B that will be great.

Comment: Reusing doesn't fit well with the idea of BDD. It either is a separate scenario, in which case it should be written up from scratch or it's minor enough that it can be alternated with [step data](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#step-data). Nesting a scenario just never makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use `context.execute_steps()` to rebuild your scenario or part of it from inside another step. I think it's worthwhile to keep your second scenario more streamlined and focused on whatever it is that you're testing, but be careful with future maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you can extract whatever you're doing in scenerio 1 into a fixture and use the fixture in both scenerios